# Why this conditional expression has the size of a float?

Tags: c

I expect the output to be "short int" but the output is "float".

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int x = 1;
    short int i = 2;
    float f = 3;
    if (sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(float))
        printf("float\n");
    else if (sizeof((x == 2) ? f : i) == sizeof(short int))
        printf("short int\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You expect `(x == 2) ? f : i` to have a type based on the value of `x`. But that is not how the C type system operates. The conditional operator is an expression, and all* expressions in C have a fixed type at compile time. It is this type that `sizeof` operates on. The value of the expression will depend on the value of `x`, but the type depends on `f` and `i` alone.

In this case, the type is the determined by the usual arithmetic conversions, which nominate `float` as the type of the result, same as if you had written `f + i`, where the result would unsurprisingly be a `float` too.

---

<sub>(*) - VLA's produce exemptions to this rule, but your question is not about one, so it's irrelevant.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the compiler to compute the size of `(x == 2) ? f : i`  and that expression is a `float`.

Remember that `sizeof` is a *compile-time* operator, and that the [`?:` ternary conditional operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) will have as type something which is convertible from both the "then" and the "else" case.

For details, refer to some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and to the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)